# PyCharm can't find a reference yet it definitely exists

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I'm trying to use a thing in `numpy.random` which I import using `from numpy.random import normal`. PyCharm tells me this is an unresolved reference despite being able to find other things in `numpy.random` such as `numpy.random.random`.

Whenever I open up a Python shell and type `from numpy.random import normal` it runs fine and I can use `normal` just as I desire in the terminal.

Why is this?

Comment: PyCharm (as many other python IDEs) can't always resolve names out of python extension modules...

Comment: How do I bypass this problem?

Comment: using a virtualenv and explicitly setting the interpreter works for me

Comment: I've done that as well. Still can't find it.

Comment: See the Pycharm bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13124 and related issues.

Answer (score 11):

Try File->Invalidate Caches/Restart...

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is that your interpreter setting is wrong. When you have multiple versions of python installed and only one has numpy installed, if pycharm choose the wrong interpreter, then you get the error.

Comment: As was suggested I've created a new virtualenv with a fresh install of numpy and it still can't find it.

Comment: So you've chosen the newly created virtualenv as project interpreter? If so , I don't know what's wrong. Maybe you should report this bug to them.

Comment: This was my problem.  I have multiple pythons installed (2.7 and 3.6). PyCharm doesn't see the 3.6.  This answer help me install the correct version to the version of python that PyCharm was using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43165320/386619

Answer (score 1):

You can also comment

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
```

Above the line of code to ignore the error message

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it is basically caused due to pycharm.But when i ran the same code in spyder it worked fine.

- Uninstall and reinstall the package

And it works!